# How to fetch array and store it in state using hooks React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I trying to fetch an array and update state using hooks

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const getItems = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await apiLink.get('...');
        const data = response.data;
        console.log(data) // show an array of objects
        setItems(data);
        console.log(items); // show empty array
      } catch(error) {
        //...
      }
    };
```

**console.log(data):**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Item name 1",
    "score": 10,
  },
  Object {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Item name 2",
    "score": 12,
  },
]
```

**console.log(items):** `Array []`

I also tried to use `const responseJSON = response.json()`, but there is an error occurs

**response.json is not a function. (In 'response.json()', 'response.json' is undefined)**

What do i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setItems` here will be called acynchronously, so would not see anything in the console just yet. However if you want to do some computation after the state for items is set, you can use a callback function using `useEffect`.

You can read more [here](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-setstate-callback-in-react) for how to use **setState Callback in a Functional Component**.

Answer (score 0):

Your component should seem something like :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });

  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await apiLink.get('...');
    setData(result.data);
  });

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.hits.map(item => (
        <li key={item.objectID}>
          <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `seItems` function here is asynchronous try keeping the log in useEffect hook you'll get the result